# Import OPML file to RSS Android?

Tags: rss

I have "liferea feed reader" on Linux for RSS feeds. Is there a way I could import all my added feeds there to Android? (NOTE: the extension of RSS exported file is "opml".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android doesn't have a built-in RSS feed reader, but there are many RSS feed reader apps (and websites) that will happily import an OPML file.

If you want to use a website, or an app with a website-synced back end, then [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/) is very popular, and you can definitely import OPML files into Google Reader. On your device you can then either visit the Google Reader webpage, or use the [Google Reader app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.reader&feature=search_result), or one of the [other many Android apps that sync with Google Reader](https://market.android.com/search?q=%22google%20reader%22&c=apps).

To import an OPML file into Google Reader, click the cog/gear icon in the top-right of the page, then click Reader Settings and then  Import/Export. You should then see the option to upload your OPML file.

Comment: Note that Google have announced that they're turning off Google Reader effective July 1, 2013.

Answer (score 2):

[RssDemon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meecel.feedreader.RssDemonAd) imports OPML files.

[JustReader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.enacu.myreader) says it does, but I couldn't find it and have asked the dev about it.